# Trying to retrieve a document by _id directly in template helper not working in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to retrieve a document directly in meteor via the `_id` of the document.

Here is my helper:

```
Template.lesson.helpers({
  lesson: function() {
      //url format: http://localhost:3000/lesson/CroFdSKNBriy7QCHL

    var url = window.location.href;
    var result= url.split('/');
    var id = result[result.length-1];
    console.log('url: '+url);
    console.log('id: '+id);
    var lessonsData = Lessons.findOne({_id: id});
    return lessonsData;
  }
});
```

This correctly grabs the id from the url.

I assume the problem is with id being in string format.

How can I pass the value in the format `meteor/mongo` is looking for the `id` to be in?  Here is the error message I receive.

> Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: lessonData is not defined

Thanks so much for any help!

Updated question to reference current error with changes suggested.

Also I can not use iron router for this project since I am using some parts of polymer that don't work well with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate this.

```
//url format: http://localhost:3000/lesson/CroFdSKNBriy7QCHL
```

You should have something like this (for example).

```
//Router.js 
    Router.route('/lesson/:_id', {
      name: 'lesson',
      data: function() { 
        Session.set('lessonId',this.params._id) //take the id from here.
        return Lessons.findOne({_id: this.params._id);
      }
    });
```

And now on the helper.

```
 Template.lesson.helpers({
       lesson: function() {
          //url format: http://localhost:3000/lesson/CroFdSKNBriy7QCHL
        var id = Session.get('lessonId')
        var lessonsData = Lessons.findOne({_id: id}); //like around says you don't need the fetch(), since you are only returning 1 object.
        return lessonsData;
     }   
   });
```

Editing your question, seems like you have a typo error, like the error says.

change the return on the helper statement to `return lessonsData`

Comment: unfortunately I can not use iron router.  So I need to get the id manually and grab it through the url.  Is there a way to convert the string format from the url into what meteor is looking for the _id type.

Comment: uggh... Thanks so much.  I didn't realize my typo.  That fixed things.  There was no type problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
var lessonsData = Lessons.findOne({_id: id}).fetch();
```

If you use findOne you do not need to use fetch you directly get the object therefore `fetch()` is not a function.

By the way if you use the iron router you can get the params of the url directly by doing `Router.current().params.yourparameter` rather than using javascript window.location.

Another error is that you have

```
var lessonsData = Lessons.findOne({_id: id}).fetch();
    return lessonData;
```

You type lessonsData on the first one with an S and not on the return.

Comment: Thanks that was a partial problem.  I am still getting an error when I remove fetch. Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: lessonData is not defined.  I still think the problem is due to id being considered a string but maybe its something else.  Unfortunately I can not use iron router as I am using some parts of polymer that won't work well with iron router.

Comment: I changed my answer to answer your second error :). It is due to a typo